# How to VLOOKUP across several columns?

Tags: excel

I've been googling this for a while, and I've found some information on this but I can't seem to relate them back to what I'm doing here. Basically I have a large data set, in column A, there is a list of unique ID tags (a combination of letters and numbers, each referencing a gene, with each column being a strain of bacteria). The table has 24 columns for 24 different strains.

If there is a gene from a different strain (i.e. not strain A) which is sufficiently similar to one from column A in a certain strain, than the ID code for that gene is put in the same row as whichever one it is similar to from strain A in the column for whatever strain of bacteria it is from.

Now here's the tricky part, not every gene in column A has a corresponding gene in another strain. If there is not a corresponding gene the value is #N/A (This was automatically generated by excel earlier when I was using the vlookup function)

I have to find a way to just pick out the rows where there are genes from column A, which have corresponding genes in strains C,D,E and F, and only those strains, and no other

Is it possible to use VLOOKUP for this? Or possible INDEX and MATCH??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried filtering? Filter each of those columns and exclude #N/A values and you should be left with only rows that have non-#N/A values in all 4.....or use a helper column, e.g. in column 25 ty this formula in row 2 copied down

`=IF(A2="","",IF(COUNTIF(C2:F2,"<>#N/A")=COLUMNS(C2:F2),"x",""))`

that will give you an "x" in rows where columns C to F are all populated with non #N/A values. You can then filter on that column alone

Comment: Literally the second I posted it popped into my head, I just wasn't sure if it would work. Thanks :)